# getting error in selecting dropdown options

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

I crerated a simple application, where i am having a dropdown and a button and two textboxes.
When i am selecting first option it should populate a text in textbox1 and on click of button it should use the textbox1 text and write a sentence in textbox2.Now when i am selecting another option in dropdown its giving an application error.

My code:

```
protected void ddSelectOption_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cp = "Optionone";
        if (ddSelectOption.SelectedValue == cp)
        {
            txtwrite.Text = "tagit";
        }
        else
        {
            txtwrite.Text = "dynamictag";
        }
    }

    protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cp = "Optionone";
        if (ddSelectOption.SelectedValue == cp)
        {
            txttag.Text =  "<u "+ txtwrite.Text + ">" + "hai </u>";
        }
        else
        {
            txttag.Text = "<u "+ txtwrite.Text + ">" + "hai </u>";            }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me .

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? If so, please tag it as such. Also, please post the error message. Kindly review http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for advice on asking questions.

Comment: On button click you want to use the text in `textbox1` and write a sentence in `textbox2`. Then why are you again comparing the cp and SelectedValue? Make the question more clear

Comment: @Jan  i am getting below error   : A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (txttag="<u tagit>hai </u>").

Comment: @Cdeez  first i am selecting "optionone" and i am getting a text in textbox1, and on button click i am getting it in textbox2 as in my question. and same time when i am selecting "optiontwo" in dropdown its giving this error : A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (txttag="<u tagit>hai </u>").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like Asp.net is warning you that you're trying to submit an HTML string (leaves you open to XSS attacks). You will need to sanitize your input first e.g. remove the tags and then proceed or if you're certain it's fine then you can turn request validation off via setting:

`validateRequest = false;`

If this is .Net 4.0 you'll have to use this:

`<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />`

To force it to use the old 2.0 validation mode as 4.0 performs request validation before the  `page` directive is parsed.

Comment: i tried removing tag its working fine , but when i tried with tag and with `validateRequest = false;` i am getting the same error.

Comment: Where did you put `validateRequest = false;`?

Comment: in `<%@ page ValidateRequest="false"%>` and in web config `<system.web> <pages validateRequest="false" /> </system.web>`i kept it

Comment: Is this a .net 4.0 app? If so you'll have to use `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />` to be able to turn it off

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if (ddSelectOption.SelectedValue!=null)
if (ddSelectOption.SelectedValue.ToString() == cp)
...
```

Everything will be ok.

Comment: hi llia.. i used as u suggested. i am still getting same error:A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (txttag="<u tagit>hai </u>").